# Calls initiated never go to Bluetooth

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth, calls

Recently my android phone stopped sending calls to my car's bluetooth when I start the call.

My phone pairs well with my car, and if I receive a call, it is sent to the car correctly. However, when I use android auto, or use the dialing service of my car's dashboard, the call is always ported via the "earpiece", and I have to manually grab the phone and select bluetooth for it to work, which is very distracting when driving.

Comment: Have you checked the **call audio** option in the Bluetooth setting  for the paired device (Car) ? This option have been resetted after a unparing, re-pairing event

Comment: I did, everything seems fine. Also, when i receive a call, it works fine. Something I forgot to mention is that if I place a call using Whatsapp, or any other app, the call audio works fine. It's just with the "Phone" app on my device. I also tried installing a new dialer, and reset the app data.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the default dialer I suspect, can you please try another alternative dialer app such as [True Phone Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hb.dialer.free&hl=en) , its been recommended on XDA, and give an update on how it works with current bluetooth setup

Comment: See if [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix) can help, it is rated well or [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.myklos.btautoconnect)

Comment: Neither solution worked, the True Phone one even made things worse, calls went to the speaker, but no UI showed the call in place, so couldn't even hang up :$ Additionally, I tried a Tasker action that sent the "change to Bluetooth" instruction every 3 seconds, for 15 seconds when a call was placed on my car... works sometimes, but not reliable enough :S